# Get records containing iframe elements with 'src="http:' with PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to get all records with iframe elements with the attribute "src" starting with "http:".

e.g.

In table "entries" there is a column "content", which contains HTML strings. These strings may contain zero or more iframe elements.

If inside "content" a record has something like this:

```
<iframe title="Some title" src="http://webpage.com" />
```

It should be returned.

I'm currently trying with the next query but results are not as expected.

```
SELECT content FROM entries WHERE content ~ '.*<iframe.*src="http:.*'
```

Comment: Try using `'<iframe[^>]*src="http:[^>]*>'` regex.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to set it as the correct answer. Would you add it as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
 '<iframe[^>]*src="http:[^>]*>'
```

Here is a [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fV8oL8/1) (see the right-side pane for more regex details)

The regex matches `<iframe` literally, then 0 or more characters other than `>`, then `src="http:` literally, then again 0 or more charactets other than `>` and the final `>`.

Comment: Just a note: this regex and others can be tested on regex101.com, choose JavaScript as regex flavor for better compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a regex like this:

```
(?i)(<iframe[^>]*title="[^>]*"[^>]*src="[^>]*"[^>]*>)|(<iframe[^>]*src="[^>]*"[^>]*title="[^>]*"[^>]*>)
```

or

```
/(<iframe[^>]*title="[^>]*"[^>]*src="[^>]*"[^>]*>)|(<iframe[^>]*src="[^>]*"[^>]*title="[^>]*"[^>]*>)/i
```

For more accurate check you can add spaces like this:

```
/(<iframe[^>]* title *= *"[^>]*"[^>]* src *= *"[^>]*"[^>]*>)|(<iframe[^>]* src *= *"[^>]*"[^>]* title *= *"[^>]*"[^>]*>)/i
```

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that the element may contain more attributes and in different orders.

Comment: Can you be more specific and give me some examples of invalid result or valid result that is out of my regexes match?